# Avoid reply message on emails (with voting buttons) except for specific case (or vote)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

We have an email (MS Outlook 2010 - Exchange server setup) template that is sent out each day to collect responses from users using voting buttons.

*For example say for ordering lunch (with Options Pizza, Burger, Noodles, Others)*

After I send out this voted email, I start receiving responses and the Tracking portion of the *Voting* presents a neat summary.

In addition to this, I'm receiving lots of emails (around 25 per day-See image below) telling me that a particular user responded with either of the four options.
[image]
I want to receive emails only when the users select *Others*. Because when they select *Others* - they will *edit the response* and send the requirement in the body of the mail.

Is it possible to selectively receive emails for mails sent out with voting option?

Comment: Are you selecting the 'Custom' option when you add the voting buttons?

Comment: Yes. The default options are *Yes; No*, *Approve; Reject*, *Yes; No; Maybe* which are not good enough for me.

Comment: Hmmm. . . I've never had to use the voting buttons before, but I'm checking if there's a way to do what you want to achieve. So far no success. I'll let you know if I come across anything.